# Tiles2 with Spring security, login error message not getting displayed

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, tiles, tiles2, apache-tiles

I am trying out Tiles2 for templating all the webpages in my new spring MVC application.
I created a login page called Login.jsp that uses j_spring_security_check for form post action.

I am successfully able to login and validate the authentication using AuthenticationProvider.
However, I am stuck on how to display the error message in case of an unsuccessful login attempt. I created a controller that will check if there a query parameter with error. The Login controller is never getting called on a normal login attempt or on an unsuccessful login attempt. The controller class is in the context:component-scan in ApplicationContext.xml.

I tried adding break points on the controller but its never getting invoked.
The endpoint I use for accessing the login page.

It seems to me like the Controller is not getting used and the login.jsp is displayed, how can I make sure that it passes through the controller?

Can you please tell me what I am missing here, I looked at lot of example configurations and answers here, I cannot find out what I am doing wrong.

Spring Version: 3.1.0
Tiles Version: 2.2.2

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login.company", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
                              @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        if(error !=null && !StringUtils.isBlank(error)){
            model.addObject("error", "Incorrect username or password.");
        }else if(logout !=null && !StringUtils.isBlank(logout)){
            model.addObject("msg", "You have been logged out.");
        }
        model.setViewName("login");
        return model;
    }
}
```

Tiles.xml

```
<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="mainLayout" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/mainLayout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="includes" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/includes.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/blank.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/footer.jsp"/>
    </definition>


    <definition name="*" extends="mainLayout">
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/{1}.jsp"/>
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

Security.xml

```
<beans:bean id="loginService" class="com.LoginService"/>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="loginService">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.company" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.company" authentication-failure-url="/login.company?error=1" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login.company?logout" />
</http>
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
</bean>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer"/>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app metadata-complete="false" version="2.5"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.company</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the problem after a few frustrating hours,  I missed the annotation-driven tag in my ApplicationContext.xml.

> `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`

so it failed to recognize the annotation driven controllers.